# react-native: Flatlist how to pass from onViewableItemsChanged to renderItem

Tags: react-native

I am trying to manipulate a component under `renderItem` in a `FlatList` when `onViewableItemsChanged` is called.

My code looks like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.data.allPosts.nodes}
    ListHeaderComponent={() => this.props.listHeader}
    onViewableItemsChange={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
    renderItem={({item}) => 
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 12 }}>
            <Video lights={true}
                ref={(ref) => this[`postRef_${item.key}`] = ref}
            />
        </View>
    }                   
/>


onViewableItemsChanged = ({viewableItems}) => {
    viewableItems.forEach((item) => {
        const { isViewable, key } = item;

        if(isViewable) {
            const ref = this[`swiperRef_${key}`];

            if(!ref) return console.log('Ref not found');
                console.log('ref', ref)
                ref.paused = false
        }
    });
}
```

My issue is that the reference keeps returning undefined. Any way around it?

Comment: Not sure if this is from bad formatting but you are missing an `=` between `onViewableItemsChanged` and `{this.onViewableItemsChanged}`

Comment: yes thanks thats bad formating

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "the reference" but if you are referring to `const ref = this[swiperRef_${key}];`

Have you bound `this` to `onViewableItemsChanged` via

`this.onViewableItemsChanged = this.onViewableItemsChanged.bind(this)`

or

`onViewableItemsChange={this.onViewableItemsChanged.bind(this}` ?